# Formula for searching a record if found it adds 1 else it makes a new record

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm new to Excel, yes sorry about this but could you help me with resources that I could use to solve my problem?

I would like a simple formula that the user would enter the Username

The forumla searches for the Username in all the A:A cells and if it could find it, it would add 1 to the cell on the right, if not it would make a Username on the bottom open cell.

[example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wxcM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a macro that will do the same thing as a formula:

Put this in your sheet code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$F$4" Then 'assuming the name you are searching is in F4
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim check As Integer

    Dim LastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = Target.Value Then
            Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 1).Value = 1
            check = 1
        End If
    Next i

    If check > 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        LastRow = LastRow + 1
        Cells(LastRow, 1).Value = Target.Value
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code, but there's an issue I would like it to add 1 if the username is entered again, this goes up to 1 only :(

Comment: Thank you for the code, I fixed the issue by doing this  Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 1).Value =  Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 1).Value + 1 Thanks again!